# To accept a String in an ArrayList in java as ReturnType

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have a variable in class XYZ named abc.
The return type of that variable is List but earlier its return type was String.So, now when a list comes as a input it is processed but when a String comes it throws Exception.
the need is to make it compatible for both datatypes List as well as String.
Please help

```
private List<String> abc;

public List<String> getAbc() {
    return abc;
}

public void setAbc(List<String> abc) {
    this.abc = abc;
}
```

Comment: you cannot have one variable with two different types. You can define a second variable and overload your method setAbc(String s) and then assign the passed string to another local variable

Comment: Which line cause exception?

Comment: you may have to provide another setter, maybe `public void setAbc(String abc) { this.abc = new ArrayList<String>(abc); }` or similar...

Comment: All remarks on overloading are valid, but you could also take a varargs of `String` as your only version of the setter, and handle conversions to single or multiple item list internally to the setter.

Answer (score 6):

The concept you are looking for is `method overloading`.

A method is defined by its name and all its parameters, so you can define two **different** methods like this:

```
public void setAbc(List<String> abc) {
    this.abc = abc;
}

public void setAbc(String abc) {
    // Collections.singletonList creates an *immutable* list
    // See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList(T)
    this.abc = Collections.singletonList(abc);
}
```

Comment: Be careful when using `Collections.singletonList`. You won't be able to add any element to this list because of its immutability. So `object.getAbc().add("def");` will throw an error. Depending on what OP wants, it would be better to wrap it in an array list.

Comment: @Abrikot on the other hand, it might be a good thing to make `getAbc()` return an immutable list, and have different methods `setAbc()`, `addToAbc()`, removeFromAbc()` etc. See for example https://refactoring.guru/encapsulate-collection

Comment: @DodgyCodeException > Surely! It really depends on what OP wants. That was a nothing more than a warning for anyone who uses this working solution and encounter an exception.

Comment: You're right, I used it as an example since I can't really say the use of OP for this method. I will add a warning about its immutability though

Answer (score 4):

If all you need is the same method name, something like this could work:

```
public void setAbc(List<String> list) {
    this.abc = list;
}

public void setAbc(String str) {
    if (this.abc == null) {
        this.abc = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    this.abc.add(str);
}
```

Do you want to append to this list or create a new list with just on entry? This one appends to list.

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<String> abc;

public List<String> getAbc() {
    return abc;
}

public void setAbc(List<String> abc) {
    this.abc = abc;
}

public void setAbc(String newItem) {
    if (this.abc == null) {
        this.abc = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    }
    this.abc.add(newItem);
}
```

You add a new method and append to the list. As mentioned from ItFreak this is called overloading.

Answer (score 0):

How can you set String to List as suggested by @ItFreak overload method for String..
Untill unless it will not work